# I want to add record to DB after "mysqli_error"

Tags: php, mysql

```
        $response[ 'error' ] = 1;
        $response[ 'message' ] = "ErrorDB";
        $response[ 'message_log' ] = "DBError:" . mysqli_error( $this->connection->getDb() );
        $this->errM->LogError($response['message_log']);
```

I want to log the error in another DB, but that seems to fail only after the line where "mysqli_error"

Comment: Any specific error that you have seen?

Comment: No error, but the log is not being added to the db. If I remove the line that contains "mysqli_error(..." the log is added to the DB successfully

Comment: Enable error logging in PHP and then see. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php